# Custom Text for Drilldown Menu "Back" Button [Foundation 6]

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

While I know I can use *data-back-button* to change the text on my drilldown menus, is it possible to change them to reflect whatever the parents of the drilldown is?

**For example, the drilldown menu works as such:**
[image: Example 1]

**And I'd like it to function as such:**
[image: Example 2]

I hope this makes sense and let me know if I can clarify. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: So you want the label to say "Back to Parent Name" instead of "Back"?

Comment: Just "Parent Name".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this but the most straightforward seems to me to be something like this:

1) Use [Foundations Drilldown options](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/drilldown-menu.html#js-options) to set a new general back button. e.g. `data-back-button='<li class="js-drilldown-back"><a class="new-back"></a></li>'`

This takes care of the styling with `.js-drilldown-back` and makes it work as a back button without additional JavaScript. It also adds a new class to the `a` for later use setting the text.

2) To change the text you can use jQuery, perhaps something like this:

```
$('.new-back').each(function(){
  var backTxt = $(this).parent().closest('.is-drilldown-submenu-parent').find('> a').text();
  $(this).text(backTxt);
});
```

All this does is scurry up the menu structure to find out what the original link text was, and then copies it to the new back button.

This should work for all levels of a drilldown as in this example: http://codepen.io/tymothytym/pen/GWbXap

FYI: There are a few mild usability concerns with using the same labels to point forward and backwards in menus as users can find this confusing, particularly with many levels. You may have already considered this, I mention it only for completeness.

Comment: This is perfect--works like I had imagined--thank you. You bring up a good point with the usability concerns. It's something I've had in mind, but wanted to consider an alternate option. Some A/B testing perhaps. Thanks again!

Comment: No probs, happy to help. Do check the selectors for your code though, I'm not totally sure they are universal!

Comment: This is perfect but is there a way to have the text and the arrows (the ones that are used to drill down) independent from each other?

Answer (score 0):

I could not change the menu structure in my project so I fixed it like this:

```
if (jQuery('.js-drilldown-back').length) {
    jQuery('.js-drilldown-back').each(function () {
        jQuery('.js-drilldown-back').find('a').text('Custom back text');
    });
}
```

With this you don't need an extra html tag.